# Read xls in robotium script

Tags: xls, robotium

I try to read an xls(simple trial) but get error:

```
    FileInputStream fi;
    File f = new File("C:\\tdata\\td.xlsx");

    fi = new FileInputStream(f);

    Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    Sheet s=w.getSheet(0);
    System.out.println("**********************"+s.getCell(0,1).getContents());



java.io.FileNotFoundException: /C:\tdata\td.xlsx: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
at com.nokia.poicollectiontool.test.Test1.testClick(Test1.java:64)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:177)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1619)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
... 16 more
```

I don't understand what the actual problem is, as file very much exists and why in the error it says "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /C:\tdata\td.xlsx"(inserts '/' before C:)

Answer (score 0):

The file must exist on device. You are trying to read file, which you have on your pc. That's why it's screaming that file does not exist. You can put it for instance on sdcard directory with adb push commnad.